# Why does moment.js subtract method not works?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to subtract 7 days to a given date using moment.js

```
var date ="2015-10-19";
var now =  moment(date);
var oneWeekAgo = moment(date).subtract(7,'days');
```

When I check values of `now` and `oneWeekAgo` have the same content both.

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2015-10-19", _f: "YYYY-MM-DD ", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}
```

However, If I subtract 7 days to current time it works.

`var oneWeekAgo = moment().subtract(7,'days');`

I've noticed that instanciate a moment without arguments change his structure, storing date on `_d` attribute instead `_i`.

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Locale, _d: Tue Oct 13 2015 13:34:50 GMT+0200 (Hora de verano romance)}
```

Why it happens? and how can I solve it?
Thanx.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Private variables of momentjs are not that simple.

`_i` is just the string you use to instanciate the momentjs object. It is not the current value of the date.

```
var date = "2015-10-19";
var now = moment(date);
var oneWeekAgo = moment(date).subtract(7, 'days');

// 2015 10 19
console.log(now.format('YYYY MM DD'));

// 2015 10 12
console.log(oneWeekAgo.format('YYYY MM DD'));
```

Comment: Missing `)` to close the console.log `;-)`

Comment: Oops. Thanks for that.

Comment: `subtract` changes the state of the instance it is called on. So just `now.subtract(7, 'day')` will change `now` too.